# Need regex to return words before the first appearance

Tags: regex

Hi I have a paragraph :

```
 output:
       I am Deepak
       I study Computers
       I find it interesting
       I like listening to music
       You also like listening to music
```

I want to extract from "output" to "I like" :

```
 output:
       I am Deepak
       I study Computers
       I find it interesting
       I like
```

This is the regex I use :
(?<=output)([^\n]*)(?=listening to music) . But I am not getting what I expected.

This is what I get :

```
 output

       I am Deepak
       I study Computers
       I find it interesting
       I like listening to music
       You also like
```

Can any one help ?

Comment: What kind of regular expressions, on what platform, in what context (an editor, a programming language, a special regex tool)?

Comment: This is the tool, I am using : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use non-greedy quantifications:

```
output[^\n]*?(?= listening to music)
```

(I suppose that you actually want the word 'output'.)